# gmaps4rails detect_location jumps on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails in a Rails 3.1.3 app and I've set detection of location on in the gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee file like so;

```
@default_map_options =
  id: 'map'
  draggable: true
  detect_location: true  # should the browser attempt to use geolocation detection features of HTML5?
  center_on_user: true   # centers map on the location detected through the browser
  center_latitude: 0
  center_longitude: 0
  zoom: 7
  maxZoom: null
  minZoom: 10
  auto_adjust : true      # adjust the map to the markers if set to true
  auto_zoom: true         # zoom given by auto-adjust
  bounds: []              # adjust map to these limits. Should be [{"lat": , "lng": }]
  raw: {}                  # raw json to pass additional options
```

This works half the time. I notice that when I hit F5 or Ctrl+r to refresh the browser it sometimes places me in Broken Hill, when I'm supposed to be in Melbourne (840kms difference).

Sometimes I see it quickly go to Broken Hill then switches to Melbourne whilst loading. Here are all the other plugins I have installed:

```
#= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
#= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery.ui.datepicker
#= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
#= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
#= require jquery.ui.slider
#= require jquery.flexslider
#= require jquery.ui.widget
#= require jquery.ui.mouse
#= require jquery.ui.touch-punch.min
#= require jQuery.BlackAndWhite
#= require form-accordion
#= require modernizr
#= require lovesjavascript
#= require jquery.tokeninput
#= require authentications
#= require inquiries
#= require registrations
#= require search
#= require tinymce-jquery
#= require jquery.sticky
#= require_self
```

I have tried with only gmaps4rails base & googlemaps in and still have the problem.

Comment: I use standard html5 geolocation. And this sometimes fails.

Comment: Cool, thought it was just me.